# What would we obtain if we set any value other than 0 or 1 to $s$ in $G_X(s)$?

Tags: probability, probability-generating-fn

> Let $X$ be a discrete RV with PGF $G_X(s) = \frac{s \cdot (2 + 3s^2)}{5}$ . Find the distribution of $X$.

Here, if we continue to differentiate and set $s=0$ in $G_X$, we obtain $P(X=0,1,2,… … …)$.

But, what happens when we set any value in between $0$ and $1$ or $2.5$, $3$ and so on?

**What would we obtain?**

What would that represent with respect to $X$?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ is nonnegative,

$$G_X(s):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X=i)s^i=E[s^X].$$

So you'll obtain sums of $P(X=i)$ with some weight $s^i$. In general you will be calculating $E[s^X]$.

Comment: what would that represent w.r.t. $X$?

Comment: @anonymous: It represents $E[s^X]$.

Comment: What is the difference with $E[s^X]$ where $s=0, 0.5, 1, 1.5... ... ...$?

Comment: @anonymous: When $s=0$ you get 1. Otherwise you get whatever $E[0.5^X]$ is. There's no other intuitive meaning.

Comment: Does $E[0.5^X]$ have any use?